# What's up with deleted wiki posts?

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt, deleted-posts

I understand that past a certain amount of rep I can see deleted posts but I'm not sure what the intended behaviour of deleted wiki/wiki excerpt posts is.

Deleted questions and answers are highlighted differently, to indicate that they are deleted however, deleted wiki and wiki excerpts are not.

Also, it appears that other users (tested as an anonymous user) can see the wiki post despite it being deleted (although they can't see the history to see that it's deleted).

An example would be https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mde/info. If you look in the history you can see it's been deleted, but as far as I can tell there's no other way of knowing.

Not sure exactly what should be done here but I'd guess:

1. Indicate visually that the wiki post has been deleted for users that should still be able to see it
2. Either:

   - Stop normal users from seeing deleted wikis
   - Allow normal users to see the history for wiki's (if they should be able to see the wiki itself).

Comment: The bug here is that the post behind the scenes was deleted as part of automatic process, when the user who wrote the first revision was nuked. It's kind of a "zombie" now, as the tag wiki still exists, but can't be edited anymore, even by 20k users.

Comment: Ugh, even *I* can't edit it, or do anything else to it, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Tim http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14865421/edit - though didn't try to save yet.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Noble effort, but [doesn't seem to affect it at all](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14865421/revisions) when saved.

Comment: @TimPost weird, [worked for me](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14865421/revisions) (though it's still deleted)